# How to deserialize Decimal of Tarantool 2.10+ response in Rust?

Tags: rust, tarantool

With Rust  select `space` contain field type `decimal` how to deserialize?
I am using [alopecosa](https://github.com/dedefer/alopecosa) crate select working fine primative type like boolean, string, number expect some new type like decimal need manual deserialize
Type I want [Decimal (rust_decimal crate)](https://crates.io/crates/rust_decimal)

Comment: What is the type you intend to deserialize it into?

Comment: @possum sorry forgot provide type I am try to rust_decimal crate type, 
https://crates.io/crates/rust_decimal

Comment: Seems tightly connected with https://github.com/orgs/tarantool/discussions/8653

Answer (score 1):

I fixed with import `tarantool::decimal::Decimal;` the crate [Rust tarantool runtime](https://crates.io/crates/tarantool) 
Just make Rust struct field as type `Decimal` from above crate it done